# How to fix "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/gaming_site" error

Tags: mysql, servlets, eclipse-oxygen

I'm setting up a new database connection but ended with "**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/gaming_site**" error!
Please help me to fix this!

I'm using mysql v8.0
Therefore I added mysql connector v8.0.12 in java build path's libraries

Code for establishing database connection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/gaming_site";
        String dbUserName = "root";
        String dbPassword = "root";

        Class.forName(dbDriver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUserName,dbPassword);


    return con;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a colon in the JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gaming_site
          ^ 
         Add this.
```

See the syntax at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html

Comment: And don't forget that the JAR file with the JDBC driver must be either in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder. (I.e. it is not enough to have it only on build path.)